# Haskell: How to change algorithm to work on any size of list?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I have this code:

```
project= [ 
  [(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)] 
  | 
    a<-[1..5],
    b<-[1..3],
    c<-[1..5],
    d<-[1..3],
    e<-[1..5],
    f<-[1..3]

  , a*b + c*d + e*f <6
  , a + c + e == 5
  , b == 3 || d==3 || f==3
  ]

x=take 1 project
main = print $  x
```

it is return a list of 3 pairs [(x,y),(x,y),(x,y)] .
There are 3 conditions:

- If you sum all the x you must get 5.
- If you sum all the `x*y` you will get less than 6.
- There is at least one `y` that equal to 3.

Now, I want exactly the same algorithm to work for any longer list for example 10 pairs. How should I do that?

Comment: Wouldn't you always get an empty list for 10 pairs? AFAICT all your coordinates are greater than or equal to `1`, so the sum of the products of components would be at least `1*1 + 1*1 + ... + 1*1 = 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
project n =
  [ x
  | x <- replicateM n $ liftA2 (,) [1..5] [1..3]
  , sum (map (uncurry (*)) x) < 6
  , sum (map fst x) == 5
  , any ((==3) . snd) x
  ]
main = print $ take 1 $ project 3
```

Or like so:

```
project n
  = filter (any ((==3) . snd))
  $ filter ((==5) . sum . map fst)
  $ filter ((<6) . sum . map (uncurry (*)))
  $ replicateM n
  $ liftA2 (,) [1..5] [1..3]
```

Comment: While this solves the problem this does not assist the OP in understanding anything.  Esp with use of things like replicateM and liftA2 which are quite advanced concepts relative to OP's level.